# DataGridView and DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datatable

I have DataGridView and DataTable with my "players".

```
        DataTable dt = Extensions.ToDataTable<Player>(PlayerList);
        Grid.DataSource = dt;
```

I want to access Player objet in doubleclick event when user clicks any cell in my grid.
How to do it?

Comment: `Grid.DataSource = PlayerList;` would do the same.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: You don't know what type it is, or whether they want to bind to a copy.

Comment: @HenkHolterman No it will not do the same in my program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a handler for the CellContentDoubleClick event of the DataGridView, then access the DataBoundItem of the row:

```
DataGridView1.CellContentDoubleClick += DataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick;

private void DataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   Player player = DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as Player;
}
```

Comment: Am I blind or there is no DataBoundItem property in DataRow?

Comment: No, there isn't, but there is in DataGridViewRow, which is what the Rows collection should be returning. However, I just realized that there was a translation problem to C#:  `DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)` should have been `DataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]`. I have fixed the answer.